# Ability to load new samples on echart zoom actions (Zoom in & zoom out)

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts

For the time series chart, on the initial load, we are displaying data aggregated for every 1 hour. when the user zoom in( for example for 4 hours) we see only 4 samples, instead, can we pull more data from the server which is aggregated for lower interval like 30 or 15 and display it in the chart when the user zoom in, display higher interval data on the zoom out.

1. On zoom in display lower intervals new data like more samples.
2. On zoom out restore the data which was already available.

Checking if this feature is available or not.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.